# Execute query stored in table without loop

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if there is any way to execute an insert query stored in a table without using loops?

```
    Query
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO Temp (Code,No,Date) VALUES    (HC076,NA,2018-01-01) GO
    INSERT INTO Temp (Code,No,Date) VALUES    (HC060,NA,2018-01-01) GO
    INSERT INTO Temp (Code,No,Date) VALUES    (HC055,NA,2018-01-01) GO
    INSERT INTO Temp (Code,No,Date) VALUES    (HC098,NA,2018-01-01) GO
    INSERT INTO Temp (Code,No,Date) VALUES    (HC010,NA,2018-01-01) GO
```

I have saving entire query inside the column and need to execute each record query without loop, Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the INSERTs together into one long string, then execute that.  Be careful with dynamic SQL, though -- "sql injection" comes to mind.

```
declare @queries table(query nvarchar(max));

insert @queries(query) values ('insert 1 GO'), ('insert 2 GO'), ('insert 3 GO');

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
   (select replace(query, 'go', '; ') from @queries for xml path(''));
print @sql;
```

Comment: iI have (HC076,NA,2018-01-01) as values to insert. I cannot use "GO" in ('insert 1 go')